# How do I resolve dart pub publish vs github pages doc directories conflict?

Tags: dart, github-pages, dart-pub

To publish to GitHub pages, documentation must be in either the repository's root directory (`/`) or in `docs`. The standard directory location for dart documentation is `doc/api`. If I try to publish a library to pub.dev, `dart pub publish` is happy with `doc/api`, but not `docs`.  I suppose one solution would be to set up GitHub Actions for the repository to generate the documentation in `doc\api`, publish the library, then generate or copy (move?) the documentation to the `docs` directory, but this seems overkill for a small library.

What is the best way to resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `.pubignore` file with the /docs folder so that this folder won't be included in pub publish.

Here is a sample of [.pubignore file](https://github.com/dart-code-checker/dart-code-metrics/blob/master/.pubignore)